# Merge two datasets by two common columns in r

Tags: r, merge

I have two datasets (DT1 and DT2) with two common columns named "CustomerID" and "Date. I want to merge/left join DT1 on DT2 by both common columns.

When I do so, I only got NA in the merging column. Why so?

```
DT1
CustomerID    Date          NumberX
1             2018-09-01    1
2             2018-09-02    1
...           ...           ...


DT2
CustomerID    Date          Netsales
1             2018-09-01    100
2             2018-09-02    103
...           ...           ...
```

When using following code:

```
new_DT <- merge(DT1, DT2, by = c("CustomerID", "Date"), all.x = T)
```

I get:

```
new_DT
CustomerID    Date          NumberX    Netsales
1             2018-09-01    1          NA
2             2018-09-02    1          NA
...           ...           ...        ...
```

I cannot understand why it all will be NA? And as previously mentioned, I want to merge based on both CustomerID and Date since the customer have bought several times in DT2, but only once a day.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Using your data published, your code works to me with result    `CustomerID      Date NumberX Netsales
1          1 2018-09-01       1      100
2          2 2018-09-02       1      103`.

Comment: The code looks fine to me as well. I would check if the columns of both data tables have the same format. For instance, class(DT1$CustomerID)==class(DT2$CustomerID) will return FALSE if it is not the case.

Comment: check the structure of both datasets with `str(DT1)` and `str(DT2)`. Are `CustomerID` and `Date` the same class in both datasets? If not maybe this causes the problem. `merge` may not recognize that the values are the same if one is of `Date` class and the other `character`